# Why is message pumping with GetMessage in DLL needed for Python but not Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, ctypes

I have a C++ DLL that utilizes the Windows API, which handles a HWND_MESSAGE window creation/registration and registers event notification via `RegisterDeviceNotification`. In Qt, I just setup a window and don't use `GetMessage`, but my window process callback works automatically, so I don't use a `GetMessage` loop to receive notifications for `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. I get device arrivals and removals without adding any additional code.

However, in Python I'm just using `ctypes` to load a DLL as a `cdll`, which works:

```
__lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("DevSystem.dll")
```

However, I need to manually use event GetMessage loop in my C++ DLL to get device arrival/removal notifications. I have to manually create a loop for it to work, which I don't understand.

Basically, these lines are the only difference Python needs to work:

```
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, WM_DEVICECHANGE, WM_DEVICECHANGE))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

1. **Why does it work by default in Qt?**
2. **Why does Python need a message
   loop to get notifications?**

Comment: If loading "DevSystem.dll" depends on the `PATH` environment variable, note that, starting with Python 3.8, you'll need to add the required directories to the secure DLL search path via [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory). More simply, if it's only dependent on finding dependent DLLs beside it in the same directory, just use the fully-qualified path of "DevSystem.dll". If you're depending on the working directory, change it to "./DevSystem.dll".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does it work by default in Qt?

The Qt application framework runs a message loop to serve the UI, and that message loop also services your callback.

> Why does Python need a message loop to get notification?

Your Python program does not contain anything that runs a message loop, and so you need to implement it explicitly.

Comment: That makes sense. There are other environments I've tried, which are C# based, which also don't require a message loop, so probably something similar is happening. I guess I thought Qt's message loop would be on another thread and wouldn't be able to pump messages to a loaded DLL.

Comment: @karamazovbros, maybe; maybe not. Each thread has a message queue. Messages in the queue are only processed in a `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` call. *Sent* messages (e.g. `WM_DEVICECHANGE`) are automatically dispatched in this call (so they're called 'non-queued', though in a literal sense, all messages are queued), but *posted* messages (i.e. 'queued' messages) have to be dispatched via `DispatchMessage`. If your window was created by the  thread that implements Qt's message loop, then messages sent to your window will be dispatched automatically when that thread calls `GetMessage`.

Comment: @kar: The scope of message processing is the thread, not the module. If a thread processes messages, those messages are dispatched to code in *any* module running on the same thread.